# Visiting zero-sum triples in a vector space

Tags: co.combinatorics, finite-fields, additive-combinatorics, hypergraph

> Is it true that for any set $A\subset\mathbb F_5^n$ satisfying $A\cap(-A)=\varnothing$, there is a subset $A'\subseteq A$ such any triple $(a,b,c)\in A\times A\times A$ with $a+b+c=0$ has exactly one or two of its components lying in $A'$? That is, no zero-sum triple has all of its components in $A'$, and no zero-sum triple is completely avoided by $A'$.

The same question can be asked for any abelian group, but (the additive group of) $\mathbb F_5^n$ is what I presently need. I do not know how relevant the assumption $A\cap(-A)=\varnothing$ is.

Comment: Probably misunderstood the question. Is $A=\{122,212,221\}$ which gives $-A=\{211,121,112\}$ not a counterexample? Larger such sets can also be defined.

Comment: @kodlu: Looks like your example refers to $\mathbb F_3^n$, not to $\mathbb F_5^n$; am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I was confused, please ignore the comment.